xaml.cs System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'
I am having problems with some code that I am trying to use. I have narrowed down the problem to a section and I am not sure how to fix it. The code is failing to download a zip file.
I thought it was because I was using Google Drive, so I went to Dropbox and it had the same result.
Here is the code I am using. If anyone with higher knowledge than me can help point out where I went wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.
private void InstallGameFiles(bool _isUpdate, Version _onlineVersion)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        if (_isUpdate)
        {
            Status = LauncherStatus.downloadingUpdate;
        }
        else
        {
            Status = LauncherStatus.downloadingGame;
            _onlineVersion = new Version(webClient.DownloadString("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9wc1btx28iz03rr3r6gkt/Version.txt?rlkey=67mgp885v82m9qdafan1se469&st=h7lchvjt&dl=0"));
        }

        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadGameCompletedCallback);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3evjysl179fjrnvxx9uu8/Build.zip?rlkey=c1rcmm7qd0n95whwmc2c2inos&st=yntg8128&dl=0"), gameZip, _onlineVersion);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = LauncherStatus.failed;
        MessageBox.Show($"Error installing game files: {ex}");
    }
}

private void DownloadGameCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string onlineVersion = ((Version)e.UserState).ToString();
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(gameZip, rootPath, true);
        File.Delete(gameZip);

        File.WriteAllText(versionFile, onlineVersion);

        VersionText.Text = onlineVersion;
        Status = LauncherStatus.ready;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Status = LauncherStatus.failed;
        MessageBox.Show($"Error downloading: {ex}");
    }
}

I was expecting the zip file to download and extract, so I made sure I was using the Windows default zip system and even tried to change the host, but I still keep getting this error.


I don't see anything really about WPF in this question - you could download and unzip in a console app rather more easily, presenting a [mcve]. I would strongly advise you to rewrite the question in that form, as the current code is incomplete, and contains various aspects which aren't relevant at all as far as I can see.

(I'd also strongly advise using HttpClient instead of WebClient - use async operations instead of callbacks, and the code will be a lot simpler.)

In DownloadGameCompletedCallback, you can check if the download succeeded by looking at e.Cancelled and e.Error.

It seems that problem is not in downloading archive but in extracting it with ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(gameZip, rootPath, true);, try to check is properties gameZip and rootPath is valid, maybe its relative path on your machine or null value. You can also try to hardcode path in ExtractToDirectory instead of passing properties to debug this method and figure out the problem

the rootPath and gameZip are set to  rootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();             gameZip = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Build.zip");

So can you unzip it manually?

no because it doesnt fully download it, gets a few kilobytes done than it throws the error at me

DownloadGameCompletedCallback is calling asynchronously, gameZip and rootPath can be not allowed in this state, try to hardcode them in DownloadGameCompletedCallback method and if it works pass with userState

thank you i will give this a try
